# Optimal machine configuration for Visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, development-environment

What would be optimal machine configuration(CPU power, memory, and drive technology) for following usage:

Visual studio 2010 and Visual studio 2012- several instances at once
Oracle navigator and MSSQL Management studio
+ some other programs (like GIMP, PDF converter, MS Office..)

The main goal is fast build and compile in Visual studio.

I have got to justify every component since it is config
for development machine at work.

There are some threads on Stackoverflow about that like: 
[SSD idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867741/ssd-drives-and-visual-studio-ide-big-improvements-real-usage-stories-no-theo)

I have not tried yet SSD proposal...

-OS Windows 8, 64bit

Comment: Laptop or desktop? With laptop, the extra ram you may want will be far more expensive than a desktop. With the former 12GB of ram will be yet  expensive, while 24GB for the later won't

Comment: It is intended for desktop configuration.. Regarding RAM, if it were up to me, I'd take 32GB RAM since it is really not expensive. But, what about just 8GB? :-)) At home I have 3 year old config with 8GB RAM and it is fine  for home use (small project and general usage)

Comment: 8GB is the actual low limit you have to stay over. Of course, it will depends on what you are doing, but as VS itself, Picture editing tools and RDBMS are all memory heavy applications, you will quickly reach your RAM limit.

Answer (score 1):

a multi-core architecture (with or without HyperThreading) will give you a performance gain when concurrently running clock cycle intensive operations, as each core has dedicated execution units and pipelining, so more cores equals less chance of applications having to timeshare e.g. while compiling.

A system with a lot of RAM will have advantages when switching between different instances of e.g. Visual Studio because their state won't need to be written away to (slower than RAM) disk, be it SSD or not.
It will also reduce disk I/O when working with Gimp, Photoshop or the likes.

The amount of cache can also have a positive influence on your daily work, because more (faster than RAM) cache will reduce the need for your system to leave the confines of the CPU and go the extra mile to read from/write to RAM.

Finally, the advantages of an SSD over "conventional" disks are mainly noticeable in disk and file access times. Booting the OS will be smoother, so will starting up programs from said SSD be. But SSD size is still fairly limited within a reasonable price range. Is it worth it? Imo, no. Once your tools have been loaded, there's little to no real need in a developer's day for SSD drives.

Comment: I can't agree with you regarding SSD. While it's true that's a fair amount of RAM is required, a descent SSD drive is, in my opinion, mandatory. When you compile quite big projects, or projects with specific build steps (SharePoint in my case), a huge number of files will be read (referenced assemblies) and temp file produced/read. I often see in my ressource monitor the queue of my magnetic SATA drive reach high values (commonly over 5, sometimes over 20 and the worst I saw was 60). In this case, I wish I could have a SSD drive in my box! And it's not that expensive... for 120€ you get 256 GB

Comment: I definitely see what you're getting at. SSD WILL help but is not the magic ingredient. The type of solutions being built and run differ greatly. Not everyone will be referencing a mountain of assemblies for example. There are alternatives that are worth taking a look at that do not involve buying additional hardware. Removing superfluous "Copy Local="True" settings where possible, limiting services and processes on a build machine OS, maybe even RAMDisk building.

Comment: Wimbo, thanks for comprehensive explanation! Anyway, I'm going to try the SSD solution as described in above link.. like:                 SSD for Windows and Program Files (typically the C: drive) + 
1 TB WD Caviar Black in 2 partitions: 1 for temp files and another for the rest of docs...

Comment: Is there a good reason to give extra money for i7 CPU over i5 CPU?

Comment: yes, because of the HyperThreading

Comment: Does anyone have a comparision of i5 vs i7 based configuration in dealing with Visual Studio?